# XML tag value not fetching using NodeList

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

I've this response XML as string

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:SRVResponse>
     <ns:Response>
        <ns1:ServiceHeader>
           <ns1:rsHeader>
              <ns1:status>
                 <ns1:finStatus>E</ns1:finStatus>
                 </ns1:status>
            </ns1:rsHeader>
        </ns1:ServiceHeader>
    </ns:Response>
</ns:SRVResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Im trying to fetch finStatus. This tag value comes with ns1 or ns2 etc sometimes. But I just need to fetch the value of finStatus.

Im trying in the following way.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                           dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
                           DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                           InputSource is = new InputSource();                                 
                            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(strResponse));
                            if(is != null) {
                                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                                NodeList idDetails =  doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "finStatus");
                                if(idDetails != null) {
                                    int length = idDetails.getLength();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                                        if (idDetails.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                            Element el = (Element) idDetails.item(i);
                                            if (el.getNodeName().contains("finStatus")) {
                                                status = getElementTextContent(el, "finStatus");
                                                System.out
                                                        .println("Status :"+status);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Method of getElementTextContent is as follows

```
public static String getElementTextContent(Element el, String elemTag) {
    String result = "";
    if(el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag) != null) {
        if(el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag).item(0) != null) {
            if(el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag).item(0).getTextContent() != null) {
                result = el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag).item(0).getTextContent();
            } else {
                result = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Im not getting any exception, but getting empty value. What is missing in this one? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you put this through a debugger ? Sometimes the best way to solve is to create a standalone program and debug that. In this case it should be easy to do.

Comment: Yeah. el.getElementsByTagName(elemTag).item(0).getTextContent() this is coming as null

Comment: To debug get rid of the chaining and see what comes back null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616983/unable-to-read-xml-with-namespace-prefix-using-dom-parser - see here

Answer (score 0):

you can try this as this is working in my code.you need to give the absolute path

Here is the xml i am using

```
     * xmlInput =
     * "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n"
     * + "    <soap:Body>\r\n" +
     * "        <ns1:LoginProcesRequest xmlns:ns1=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/BioRad_jws/BR_GetSFDCLogin/GetSFDCDetailsProcess\">\r\n"
     * + "           <ns1:Login>1000</ns1:Login>\r\n" +
     * "           <ns1:Company>1000</ns1:Company>\r\n" +
     * "        </ns1:LoginProcesRequest>\r\n" + "    </soap:Body>\r\n" +
     * "</soap:Envelope>";
     */
```

Transform the response using

```
 StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, new StreamResult(out));
        String response = out.toString();

DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                    response)));

            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

            header.setSessionId((String) xpath
                    .evaluate(
                            "/Envelope/Body/LoginProcessResponse/loginResponse/sessionId",
                            doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
```

Comment: What are you trying to fetch?

Comment: it is fetcching sessionid from response.response also have the similar format as the request that i have shared

Comment: Ok Vikram. Let me check and get back to u

Comment: can you share your updated code which you are trying

Comment: System.out.println((String) xpath.evaluate("/Envelope/Body/SRVResponse/Response/ServiceHeader/rsHeader/status/finStatus",doc, XPathConstants.STRING));

Comment: you can test it with my response XML

Comment: you need to transform your response to string and then perform the same operation.check the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156312/discussion-between-yakhoob-and-vikram-saini).