# Converting from String to XML

Tags: java, xml, rest

I was trying to convert a string representation of a XML document to a org.w3c.dom.Document object, however when attempting to parse the string I get an empty nodelist collection when I call: `NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("wb:data");`

Below is a complete example which runs on its own.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String query_url = "https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/ARB/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?date=2015:2018";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(query_url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(25000);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();

            InputStreamReader ins = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(ins);

            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
             String line;
             int index=0;
              // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
              while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
              {
                  if (index++ == 0) continue;
                content.append(line + "\n");
              }
              bufferedReader.close();

            // parsing the JSON output, extracting all the population information belonging
            // to a country

            String response = content.toString();

            try  
            {  

                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));

                NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("wb:data");
                Node test = nodeList.item(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } 
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to be able to find nodes representing the  element in the xml document, but got an empty nodeList.

Comment: Passing namespace prefixes to `getElementsByName()` will not work. The prefix is not part of the elements name.

Comment: Did you try changing to `document.getElementsByTagName("data")`? `wb` is the prefix for the element.

Comment: I just tried it then, currently makes no difference.

Comment: `if (index++ == 0) continue;` - Why are you skipping the first line?

Comment: This link should help you. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14252/adx_j_parser.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to read xml with namespace prefix using DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616983/unable-to-read-xml-with-namespace-prefix-using-dom-parser)

Comment: @Sean Bright Otherwise this error appears: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. I'm skipping this section : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: The linked duplicate will help you. Additionally, there is no reason to build a `String`, you can pass the return value from `conn.getInputStream()` directly to `DocumentBuilder.parse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the following code. I am able to parse and I able to get the information for country.

```
try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));

        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println(root.getNodeName());
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName(root.getNodeName());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("Country Name : "  + eElement.getElementsByTagName("wb:country").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```